# Placement of 都 in a sentence with 每

Tags: grammar, hsk

The following dialogue is from the book HSK Standard Course 2:

A: 你每天几点起床？

B: 我每天六点起床。

Where would 都 be placed in A and B respectively? After 天 or after 点?

Answer (score 1):

都 has the meaning of "all", "entirely" (统统，完全) when used as an adverb that described the adjective or verb. In here, the proper place of 都 (adverb) is after 每天 (adjective).

A: 你每天**都**几点起床？

B: 我每天**都**六点起床。

Comment: Interestingly 我都每天六点起床 can work as "even I wake up at six o' clock" and 你都每天几点起床 sounds like it could also work as a more aggressive interrogation? (Out of practice native speaker without formal education, apologies in advance if I'm mistaken)